# How to migrate a Dreamweaver site into Kentico

Tags: content-management-system, dreamweaver, photoshop, kentico, frontpage

I have a site that was originally built with FrontPage and then transferred over into Dreamweaver. There's a lot of old coding in there and a lot of image maps (think PhotoShop image slicing) for navigation etc. I need to move the site over to Kentico (not my choice) and I'm wondering if there is an easier way of doing it.

I was able to rebuild the whole template in Kentico and now I'm left with creating all the pages and importing content. Currently I'm copying and pasting all the content (text) into the pages I've built and I'm uploading all pdfs and images into the new system. That's all fine and dandy, but there are literally HUNDREDS of pages and THOUSANDS of pdfs. Is there any easier way of doing this? I'm going crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Regrettably there is no easy way to achieve your goal as Kentico is ASP.NET application and your website is built with HTML pages at the moment.

You will need to manually transfer all the pages or you can use Kentico API to handle this programatically but you will need to parse the HTML pages on your own, so in this scenario... the best option is really to transfer all the content manually (or you can pay one of [Kentico partners](http://www.kentico.com/Partners) to do this for you).